# How To Create ToJsonAsync Extension Method?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, async-await

I  Create an Extension Method that Convert Obj To Json :

```
 public static class JsonExtention
 {
    public static string ToJsonAsync(this object initialTags)
    {

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(initialTags);
    }
 }
```

now I want use this in other method:

```
   public async Task<IList<SkillViewModel>> GetAllSkillAsync()
    {
        var ViewModel =
            _mapper.Map<IList<Skill>, IList<SkillViewModel>>(source: await _skills.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync.ToJsonAsync());

        return ViewModel;
    }
```

After Use it Show This Error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

alson When Use `Task<string>` in `ToJsonAsync`
show this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Comment: `ToJsonAsync` sounds like its misnamed since its not returning a `Task<string>`.

Comment: @danielA.white Yes i do this work but show error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence of `await` is lower than `.` So the part of your code:

```
await _skills.AsNoTracking().ToJsonAsync()
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var thing = _skills.AsNoTracking().ToJsonAsync();
await thing;
```

When you want the equivalent of:

```
var thing = await _skills.AsNoTracking();
thing.ToJsonAsync()
```

Use parentheses to fix the order:

```
(await _skills.AsNoTracking()).ToJsonAsync()
```

But this still isn't quite there as `AsNoTracking()` doesn't produce an awaitable result either. You need to do something like:

```
(await _skills.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()).ToJsonAsync()
```

or

```
(await _skills.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ToJsonAsync()
```

Then you'll first `await` a task that uses async I/O, and then when that task is completed, finish your task by calling your extension method on it.

(Since the extension method is not itself involved in this asynchronicity, it should probably just be called `ToJson()`).

Comment: I don't think we know that `AsNoTracking` returns a `Task<T>`.  It's likely that the OP just wants to make `ToJsonAsync` a real asynchronous method at least based on the name.

Comment: @juharr I'm pretty sure it's the EF one and it definitely doesn't return a `Task<T>`. I just fixed that.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.